# List ordering not formatting right and page numbers in footer right side

Tags: header-footer, lists, page-numbering

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

 \newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{0.2in}}
 \newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
 \newcommand{\di}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\vitem}{\vs \item}

 \pagestyle{plain}
 \begin{document}

 \Large
 \hfill bob

 \hfill time

 \hfill  class

 \hfill  3/25/2015

 \textbf{Problem 1:}
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
 \item \Theta(n^{0.35})
 \item \Theta(n^{0.9})
 \item \Theta(\log_2(n))
 \item \Theta(n \log_2(n))
 \item \Theta(5^{n})
 \item \Theta(1)
 \item \Theta(8^{n})
 \item \Theta(n^{2})
 \item \Theta(1)
 \item \Theta(n)
 \end{enumerate}

 \end{document}
```

my list isn't formatting correctly it doesn't add the items in a list structure. Instead of placing each item in order in the list most items share the same letter which isn't correct.I also need to put page numbers in footer area right corner. I'm new to latex please help!

Comment: You need to put dollar signs around the maths in each item.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As @cfr says, you're trying to write stuff in math mode without actually telling LaTeX to enter math mode. When I surround your math code with `$`'s, I don't see the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell TeX when to switch to maths mode. For inline maths, you can do this using `$...$` or `\(...\)`.

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{0.2in}}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\di}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\vitem}{\vs \item}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

  \Large
  \hfill bob

  \hfill time

  \hfill  class

  \hfill  3/25/2015

  \textbf{Problem 1:}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item $\Theta(n^{0.35})$
    \item $\Theta(n^{0.9})$
    \item $\Theta(\log_2(n))$
    \item $\Theta(n \log_2(n))$
    \item $\Theta(5^{n})$
    \item $\Theta(1)$
    \item $\Theta(8^{n})$
    \item $\Theta(n^{2})$
    \item $\Theta(1)$
    \item $\Theta(n)$
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: maths items]

### Tidying Up

This puts the page number in the bottom right of the page and uses `\maketitle` to create the information at top right. `titling` is used for the custom formatting of the title, and `fancyhdr` for the footer.

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,titling}

\newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{0.2in}}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\di}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\vitem}{\vs \item}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}%
  \fancyhf[rf]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcommand*\classtime[1]{%
  \gdef\makeclasstime{\Large\raggedleft #1\par}}
\newcommand*\class[1]{\gdef\makeclass{\Large\raggedleft #1\par}}
\pretitle{\Large\raggedleft}
\posttitle{\par}
\preauthor{\Large\raggedleft}
\postauthor{\par}
\predate{\raggedleft}
\postdate{\par}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\makeclasstime\makeclass}

\begin{document}

  \title{}\author{bob}\classtime{time}\class{class}\date{3/25/2015}

  \maketitle

  \textbf{Problem 1:}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item $\Theta(n^{0.35})$
    \item $\Theta(n^{0.9})$
    \item $\Theta(\log_2(n))$
    \item $\Theta(n \log_2(n))$
    \item $\Theta(5^{n})$
    \item $\Theta(1)$
    \item $\Theta(8^{n})$
    \item $\Theta(n^{2})$
    \item $\Theta(1)$
    \item $\Theta(n)$
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: footer and title]